# Field is not setting to NULL value via DataStage

Tags: administration

There is an interface between Salesforce and DataStage for User object and Users are updated in Salesforce via DataStage job. There is a text field "District" on User object which has no special attributes, just a normal text field. DataStage is trying to update a particular User's District from some value 'ABC' district to NULL value. However, the field "District" still shows the same value "ABC" and not blank/null value. The success file from DataStage does say that it updated the item successfully, however when it enters Salesforce zone, the field is not updated on the user record.

Please advise what can be the issue and how we can resolve this to set the field to null value.

Comment: Does using an empty string "" work instead?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not familiar with DataStage, but when updating records through the API, you need to explicitly set fields to null using the [fieldsToNull](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421117) property. In my experience with other integration tools, just setting a null on the field won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will check with DataStage team on this point.

Comment: Also, may be a stupid question(since I have not worked explicitly on Web Services/Integration), this should be done in code from DataStage team side? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
Additionally, it is worth checking for any before Triggers / workflows which could be resetting the District to the incumbent value.
Also worth checking if setting it to null via the UI manually works.

---

What does the interface comprise of ? Is it DataLoader scheduled using Windows Task Scheduler, or a Cron ?

What is the value that the interface is inserting to the set the value to NULL?

If it is the DataLoader, then check your settings to see if the field "Insert Null Values" is checked.

To insert null values using bulk api instead of leaving that cell empty in the csv file you need to populate"#N/A" in that.

Reference : 
http://www.interactiveties.com/b_bulk_api_nulls.php

Comment: Hi, The issue is not with Data Loader updating data in Salesforce, issue is with DataStage trying to update the field. DataStage is our Interface tool.

Comment: Data stage is the tool as Vimal mentioning

Comment: The post says "There is an interface between Salesforce and DataStage" - it seems to suggest there there is an interface BETWEEN Salesforce and DataStage. It doesnt make clear that DataStage *IS* the interface.

Comment: Sorry for misconception techtrekker. But I hope you got the point. Let me know if you have any more queries. Please advise.

Comment: Does manually setting District to null via the UI work alright ? Can you see the value that the interface is trying to set it to in the success file ?

Answer (score 0):

vimal are you sure there are no triggers/formulas updating the field?

I would try to 
1) See in the dev console if there are any workflows/formulas/triggers updating
2) Brute method : try to delete the field in a sandbox and it won't let u delete in case the trigger/workflow is updating the field.

Than that I would be curious to know why a null value would not be updated!!!
Hope this helps!!!

Comment: There are no triggers/formulas/workflow rules updating the field. Also, via Data Loader the field does get updated to null value. The issue is when Data Stage is trying to update teh field to null value, it does not work. I confirmed with Data Stage team if they also have made sure that the field should compute to null value if it is blank, and they confirmed from their side too.

Comment: Does your log from Data stage throw back the updated salesforce record Id? If so are you able to see the last updated date/last updated by to be from data stage user!!! May be something is failing when the records are being updated!!!Just a guess!!